Libreboot build error: ERROR ./build: this command as root is not permitted
I have problem. After ./build roms all command I get ERROR ./build: this command as root is not permitted.
I changed the owner to normal user of the lbmk directory but it didn't help.
I building Libreboot for ThinkPad X220t

Can you check with the id command whether you are actually running as root?
It should return a uid that is not 0 (aka. root)
You might be logged in as a root user (maybe you used sudo su before?)
In any case you also need to log in as a normal user. Many of the commands are not necessary as root and therefor shouldn't be ran as root (use root/sudo as rarely as possible)
